# Can't connect to RDS from EC2 using terraform created infrastructure

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, terraform, amazon-vpc

I created the infrastructure manually following the steps provided in the link: [connecting-to-a-database-within-an-amazon-vpc](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/connecting-to-a-database-within-an-amazon-vpc/).

I could connect to RDS in private subnet from ec2 in public subnet perfectly. That is exactly what I wanted.

But when I tried to create the same exact replica using terraform, it just doesn't connect.

The command:

```
nslookup <my-hostname>
```

gives me the Private IP.

The command:

```
telnet x.x.x.x 5432
```

results in "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out"

The command:

```
netstat -an | grep x.x.x.x
```

shows "SYN_SENT".

I tried allowing all the IP's in RDS security group by adding 0.0.0.0/0. That didn't work.

I tried to create RDS instance manually, but added it to terraform created VPC and tried to connect using terraform created ec2 instance. That didn't work.

Am i missing something ? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

troubleshooting steps:

1. Check security group's egress (outbound rules) on your public ec2 instance,

Make sure it allows outbound rules with port `5432` to access rds (which is in private subnets)

2. Check security group's ingress (inbound rules) on your rds instance. Maybe sure it allows port `5432` from public ec2 instances CIDR ips or security groups.

If not, please update your terraform codes according.

Comment: I have kept outbound rules as "All traffic" for ec2. And i have allowed the port 5432 for all by setting 0.0.0.0/0 in rds security group. It is still not working

Answer (score 0):

The ec2 instance is in public subnet. That would mean ideally traffic would go from NAT Gateways. So I would suggest to edit the security group rule of RDS add a rule to allow public IPs of NAT Gateways to be accessible on the port 5432.